# How to know if an adapter is running on MobileFirst Development Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Is there some way to know if an adapter is running in the MobileFirst Development Server or if it has been deployed to a full server?

**--Update--**

Specifically, I want to find out, **from the adapter's code itself, if the adapter is being executed in a developer's machine or if it is being executed in WAS/Tomcat/non-development Liberty Profile**.

I want to know this in order to be able to leave unprotected some adapter procedures intended for testing; this testing procedures would look similar to this

```js
function testThisAdapter() {
    if (isDevelopmentServer()) {
        return doMyTestStuff();
    } else {
        return {isSuccess: false, errors: ['nice try']};
    }
}
```

**--Update--**

This is what I am using with Idan's answer

```js
function isDevelopmentServer() {
    var clientRequest = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
    var url = clientRequest.getRequestURI();
    var pattern = /\/dev\/invoke/;
    return pattern.test(url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: When using the 6.3 (or earlier) Studio MoblieFirst Development Server, all adapter requests go through a development servlet. The request URL will contain a **/dev/** in it: `http://serverIp:10080/my-project-name/dev/invoke?adapter=my-adapter-name&procedure=my-procedure-name`. See here: [Endpoints of the MobileFirst Server production server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/r_rest_api_endpoints.html)

That's the only differentiator that I know of. I am not sure you can use that in your adapter code. Maybe in the client, if you'll somehow manage to retrieve this URL or validate its existence, then you could devise appropriate logic for the app.

---

See the following user documentation topic: [Vitality queries for checking server health](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/admin/r_vitality_query.html)

> Use IBM® Worklight® vitality queries to run a health check of your
>   server, and determine the vitality status of your server.
>
> You generally use the IBM Worklight vitality queries from a load
>   balancer or from a monitoring app (for example, Patrol).
>
> You can run vitality queries for the server as a whole, for a specific
>   adapter, for a specific app, or for a combination of. The following
>   table shows some examples of vitality queries.

For an adapter, the query would be: `http://<server>:<port>/<publicWorkLightContext>/ws/rest/vitality?app=MyApp&adapter=MyAdapter`

The user documentation topic contains more information and examples.

Comment: My apologies, Idan: the title of my question is misleading. I'm editing the question to clarify its intend. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using the CLI, `mfp invoke my-adapter:myfunction` results in a call to `http://serverIp:10080/my-project-name/invoke`, so checking for **/dev/** does not cover all cases